# How can I allocate a matrix of 10^6 rows?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to allocate memory for matrix for 250000 or more rows.
But Matlab is showing the Out Of Memory Error. I really don't understand how to allocate memory.
What I have done is:

```
temp = zeros(1000*1000)
```

How can I allocate a matrix of 10^6 rows?

Comment: `temp = zeros(1000*1000)` would generate a square matrix of 10^6 rows, i.e. 10^6*10^6 entries, which is much too much too much too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each number (`double`) takes 8 bytes. You are allocating a 1000000 by 1000000 matrix (remember, `zeros(n)` creates an `n` by `n` matrix). That's 1000000000000 elements taking a total 8000000000000 bytes. That's a lot of bytes. To realize how many, divide it by 1024 a few times to get the size in kB, GB, TB, etc. After dividing 3 times, we see that it amounts to 7.3TB. Huge!

There is a way to work with huge matrices like this as long as most elements of the matrix are zeros. You can look up [sparse matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: do this

```
temp = zeros(1E6,1);
```

---

Long answer:
Per [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html), `zeros` returns an  `NxN` matrix when given one argument.  So you are actually creating a full `1E6 x 1E6` matrix, which is ridiculously huge (just shy of 10 terabytes of memory).